# how to process these data in these data frame and do binary logistics regression?

Tags: r

The data is saved in a `.txt`. There are 200 words saved in the same text. How can I input these raw material into R and do binary logistics regression for `each of these words`?

```
num 0 0.010752688172
num 0 0.003300330033

thanksgiving 0 0.0123456790123
thanksgiving 0 0.0016339869281
thanksgiving 0 0.00338983050847

off 0 0.00431034482759
off 0 0.00302114803625
off 1 0.001100110011
off 0 0.00377358490566
off 1 0.00166112956811
off 1 0.00281690140845
off 0 0.00564971751412
off 0 0.00112994350282
off 0 0.003300330033
off 0 0.0042735042735
off 1 0.00326797385621
off 0 0.00159489633174
off 0 0.00378787878788
```

Comment: You need `read.table` to get the data in, and `glm(y~x, data = yourdata, family = binomial)` for the model. Let us know if you have problems!

Comment: @MattParker  I know how to do binary logistics regression for one word. But as you can see, I don't know when I have hundreds of words and the first column is the name of the words.

Comment: Ah, my apologies!  I didn't read carefully enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it with the `plyr` package:

```
# Load the plyr library
library(plyr)

# Read in the data
allwords <- read.table("words.txt")

# Name the variables more meaningfully than this
names(allwords) <- c("word", "y", "x")

# dlply iterates over the data.frame, splitting by "word", 
# and running a glm with the arguments formula = y ~ x and family = binomial
# and returns a list of the resulting glm objects
models <- dlply(allwords,
                .var = "word",
                .fun = glm, formula = y ~ x, family = binomial)

# It's then easy to iterate over that list using lapply, llply, ldply, etc.
# (depending on what you want back out)
# Summarize:
llply(models, summary)

# Get all the coefficients
ldply(models, coef)

# Get AICs
# Not that you can compare these among word-models, but you get the idea.
ldply(models, AIC)

# Or, if you want to work with a particular model
models$num
```

Comment: It works if the first column consists purely of words. The only problem is that there are not only  words, but phrases in the first column, which have spaces in between. Do you think there are any solutions?

Comment: That depends very much on how your input file is formatted.  If you open the file with a text editor, are there any kind of delimiters for phrases?  e.g., `"this is a phrase" 1 0.0245`

Comment: Because if the phrases look like `this is a phrase 1 0.0245`, that's going to be tricky.  That would make a good question, I think.

Comment: well, i could add delimiters in the txt like  `"this is a phrase" 1 0.0245`. How can I make it then?

Comment: If they're quote-delimited, `read.table` shouldn't have any problem identifying that as one value in the 'word' column.  Works for me, anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm lazy, so:

```
allwords <- unique(dataframe[,1])
firstword <- dataframe[dataframe[,1]==allwords[1],]
```

etc. will break your data up by word.   But you don't need to create `firstword`, `secondword`, ... since it's just as easy to use one of the `apply` functions to execute your regression function for each value of `allwords`